# Spring Boot : Recipe to repeatably get access token based on authorisation header

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-webclient

So I have this situation.
I am coding inside a controller API in spring boot that gets a request with authorisation header.
I need to hit a token endpoint with this header to get the access token.
After this I need to hit an API with this toke to get some information.

Now one way of approaching this is to ,

1. Create a clients one to get the token .
2. Create another client to hit the actual API.
3. Then when my API received the request , then hit these above endpoints in succession to get
   the job done. Also, need to take care of caching the token so that we dont end up doing this
   every time.

Because this looks like a pattern I want to create a system where i can create one client kind of like the Spring `WebCLient` and that can take care of hitting the token uri when required.
But all documentation I am reading suggest providing a token url(which I have) and also clientid/secret in the configuration.(These I dont. I only have the incoming auth code).
Is there a programmatic way I can achieve the same with webclient ?

Comment: Have you explored feign client.

Comment: I. havent used Feign before. Are there example of such an use. case there. ?

Comment: Yes, it's a declarative web client. you can check the basics here https://www.baeldung.com/intro-to-feign.

Comment: I ended up using web client with a configured `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository` and use that to create a `webClient` that can use the oauth details in the properties files.